# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Could not find file

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access

I don`t know where to find it was!

Program was working properly, but once it happened

```
Private Sub InserPP_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)HandlesMyBase.Load

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet2.plump' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

    Me.PlumpTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet2.plump)

End Sub
```

An unhandled exception of type `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` occurred in `System.Data.dll`

Additional information:

```
Could not find file 'F:\proj visual\test1\test1\bin\Debug\plump.accdb'.
```

Comment: Are you running the project in the debugger?  Did you change the name of the data file?  Did you change the `Copy to output directory` property to `Never Copy`?  Have you written your connection string yourself or used an auto-generated one?  If the former, what is it?

Comment: @jmcilhinney  yes. i try with other types but not solved..

Comment: That comment doesn't answer any of the questions that I asked.

Comment: Ah, I got the name wrong but the result is the same.  If you tell the IDE to not copy your data file to the output directory then it won't copy the data file to the output directory.  Why should it then be a surprise that the data file is not found in the output directory?  You should only use that option if you intend to put the data file in the output directory yourself (I can't think of any reason to do that) or you are connecting to a database in a different location. Neither of those applies in your case so don't use that option. `Copy if newer` is generally most appropriate.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Copy to output directory is  Do not copy

ConnectionString is auto. i used Dataset, DataGridView

Comment: @jmcilhinney i try with Copy if newer but not solved.
i said i trying with other types ! Copy if newer,Never Copy,Copy always
and i copy database in debug folder but not solved.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i try again now to copy database to debug folder, problem solve know :| tnx for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant.  Those are not "types".  Just a language problem I think.  All's well that ends well.  That said, you shouldn't have to copy manually.  If you have it set to `Copy if newer` or `Always copy` (or the like) and it's not being copied on a successful build then something would seem to be wrong with your IDE.  If you have it set to `Do not copy` or the like then your existing data file will be deleted on each successful build, which you obviously don't want.